# How to import Stackdriver logs into BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl, stackdriver

Is there a way to load logs from app engine into BigQuery on Google Cloud Platform?

I'm attempting to use federated querying to load Stackdriver log files in Cloud Storage. However BigQuery cannot load some of the field names written by Stackdriver.

The log files are newline-delimited JSON, with records that look like

```
{  
   "insertId":"j594356785jpk",
   "labels":{  
      "appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name":"aef-my-instance-20180204t220251-x59f",
      "compute.googleapis.com/resource_id":"99999999999999999",
      "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name":"c3453465db",
      "compute.googleapis.com/zone":"us-central1-f"
   },
   "logName":"projects/my-project/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout",
   "receiveTimestamp":"2018-02-08T02:59:59.972739505Z",
   "resource":{  
      "labels":{  
         "module_id":"my-instance",
         "project_id":"my-project",
         "version_id":"20180204t220251"
      },
      "type":"gae_app"
   },
   "textPayload":"{\"json\":\"blob\"}\n",
   "timestamp":"2018-02-08T02:59:54Z"
}
```

But BigQuery returns an error on this input: `query: Invalid field name "compute.googleapis.com/zone". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.`

Is there any way to ingest this kind of log into BigQuery?

I'm specifically interested in extracting just the `textPayload` fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can export **Stackdriver** logs into **BigQuery**

In **Google Cloud Platform** console, **Stackdriver Logging** >> **Exports** >> **Create Export**.
Create a filter `resource.type="gae_app"` and fill the **Sink Name** on right and choose **BigQuery** as **Sink Service** then select the dataset to export to from **Sink Destination**. https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/exports

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#dest-create

Comment: Thanks Samir. These logs are already exported to Cloud Storage though. I'm looking to ingest them from Cloud Storage

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. As you described you are interested in specific field `textPayload` which is luckily valid field name, you can load the file by specifying the schema `textPayload:STRING,timestamp:STRING` (not using autodetect) and enable the option https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.ignoreUnknownValues
Otherwise if you are interested in all fields (or fields are not valid to be BQ field-name) you can use DataFlow (see https://cloud.google.com/solutions/processing-logs-at-scale-using-dataflow)

Comment: That worked! Also for benefit of others, the "Ignore unknown values" is available in the UI as well. Marking this answer correct 

Comment: When doing an export from Stackdriver to BigQuery, I cannot select the table (only the dataset). How can I specify the table in the dataset I want the logs will go in?