# Options for exporting past logs from Gcloud Logging to Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

I've been trying to export about 2 months' worth of logs from gcloud logging to BigQuery - past logs, not a real-time sink route. This will likely be around 1.5 Million distinct log rows.

Is this possible? I just want to export past logs to BigQuery. I'll even settle for a csv that can be uploaded. Anything.

Steps attempted so far:

1. Downloading logs from GCP Legacy Logs Viewer (not enough, only able to download what's in the viewer)
2. Downloading logs from GCP Logs Explorer (again, recommends up to 10,000 logs before directing to the Exporting Logs Google Cloud page
3. Viewing in Cloud Shell (can probably in theory see the logs, but not sure if I want to gcloud logging read 1.5million entries)
4. Downloading from Cloud Shell (unsure as to what my destination folder is, or whether i would have to run the read command beforehand)
5. Creating a sink from gcp logging to Bigquery via Cloud Shell (worked, but only for real time logs as per the documentation)

For context, I'm a SQL gremlin not versed in Terminal commands or complex code. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to export the logs to GCS, and then to load this JSONL format to BigQuery? It should be the same format.

Comment: 1) Before posting a question, do your research (this question has already been asked on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711835/how-to-import-stackdriver-logs-into-bigquery) and Google has written a guide https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2 2) Do not say you tried and failed. Show exactly what you tried and the errors. You could have made a simple mistake. Read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley Thanks for the feedback! The existing thread doesn't really answer my question re: past logs, as the export options are for future sinks only. I will look into the rest api option to see if it returns the fields that I need!

Comment: Seems like a duplicated question, best scenario may be to [download old logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface#download_logs) and create a sink from now on to [export logs to BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711835/how-to-import-stackdriver-logs-into-bigquery) as explained above.

Comment: @Pit You can only download 10k logs in this manner. NONE of the provided links are a solution to OP's question. Once again Google leads me to a question that is a problem I have precisely, which was carelessly closed.